# After next occurence of {char} in vim

Tags: vim, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editor

I know by `t{char}` I can move the cursor before the next occurrence of the {char}. but I want to find a way to move cursor **after** the next occurrence of a character.

Is there any native way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this family of command is limited to `fFtT` and `,;` to repeat.

But you can always do `fxl` to jump to the next `x` and move the cursor one character to the right.